# Intellij: Sass to CSS: file watcher output folder

Tags: intellij-idea, sass, compilation, file-watcher

I have IntelliJ Ultimate Edition and I'm compiling .scss files to .css. The problem is that every .scss file is compiled to .css in the same folder. I don't want that.

My folder structure is like so:

`assets
-- css
---- main.css
-- scss
---- folder
-------icons.scss
-------elements.scss
---- folder
-------navigation.scss
---- main.scss`

The main.scss contains all the necessary files to compile to .css. But I ONLY want to compile main.scss to ../css/main.css when I make changes in one of these files/folders in this structure. How can I do that? Thanks so much.

---

Current settings in the Edit Watcher window in IntelliJ:

Program: `D:\Program Files (x86)\Ruby22\bin\scss.bat`

Arguments: `--no-cache --update $FileName$:$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css`

Output paths to refresh: `$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css:$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css.map`

Working directory: `C:\localhost\www\website\assets\sass`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try changing your watcher as follows:

```
Arguments: --no-cache --update $FileName$:$ProjectFileDir$/assets/css/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css
Output paths to refresh: $ProjectFileDir$/assets/css/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css:$ProjectFileDir$/assets/css/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css.map
```

If your `main.scss` imports all your partial `.scss` files, and **Track only root files** is enabled in file watcher settings, the `../css/main.css` will be created/updated when you make changes in any of these files

Answer (score 0):

I am having folder structure as given below.
all partial.scss file imported in ecom-styles.scss

```
assets
-- css
---- ecom-styles.css.css
-- scss
---- _file1.scss
---- _file2.scss
---- _file3.scss
---- _file4.scss
---- ecom-styles.scss
```

I changed my watcher in IntelliJ as follows and it works for me

```
Arguments: $FileName$ $FileParentDir$/css/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css
Output paths to refresh: $ProjectFileDir$/css/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css:$ProjectFileDir$/css/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css.map
```